# SQl server data tools (SSDT - BI) for SQL Server 2014

Tags: ssis, ssas, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

We are upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014 and I tried to install SQL server data tools for 2014 for SSIS, SSAS. From all the forums I read online, I installed Visual studio 2013 on my machine first and then I added SSDT 2014 for Visual studio 2013.

Is this the right way to do SSDT-BI 2014 Installation?

Comment: Sounds right to me, are you having issues?

Comment: No Issues, Thank you for your response.Just wanted to confirm after all confusion I'm in to, reading different blogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install only SSDT-BI for SQLServer2014, without requiring VS2013 license, then follow the below steps to setup development environment for SSIS, SSRS and SSAS.

1. Install [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40764)
2. Install [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated) Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40777)
3. Install [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313)

Answer (score 1):

SSDT for Visual Studio 2013 has 2 versions: The one that has only DB tooling and other with BI components. You need to look for "SSDT-BI"
Here you go:

[Microsoft download link for SSDT-BI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313)

For VS 2015 and SQL Server 2016, the current version of SSDT comes with both SQL Server tooling AND BI components, so it's one download.

Hope this helps!